# How do I stop leftBarButtonItem from disappearing when navigationItem.titleView and rightBarButtonItem take up most of the UINavigationBar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a `leftBarButtonItem` (using a custom view) that's acting as a replacement for a back button (as custom views can't be used on `backBarButtonItem`). I've also got a `rightBarButtonItem` (also using a custom view) and a custom titleView.

Everything works fine and dandy when the `leftBarButtonItem` is smaller than a certain width. The `rightBarButtonItem` can be huge and the titleView will resize and truncate to fit the available space, which is exactly how it should be, and how I want it.

However, with the same dimensions reversed (`rightBarButtonItem` smaller than a certain width and `leftBarButtonItem` huge), the `leftBarButtonItem` disappears entirely, and the `titleView` stretches to fit the entire space that previously would have held both the `leftBarButtonItem` and the `titleView`.

I tried swapping the custom views to see if it was something I had done, but the same problem persisted with the views swapped, again only on the `leftBarButtonItem`. I also tried using a regular title, without the custom `titleView`, to no avail.

In the documentation for `UINavigationItem`, under `leftBarButtonItems`, it notes that "If there is not enough room to display all of the items in the array, those that would overlap the title view (if present) or the buttons on the right side of the bar are not displayed." However, there should be more than enough room to fit both buttons and the title, as demonstrated by having a huge `rightBarButtonItem` and a truncated title. Not to mention, there is only a single `leftBarButtonItem`, not multiple, and I need it to appear to replace the back button functionality.

Any ideas on how to stop this from happening? Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[TitleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 44)];
self.navigationItem.titleView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

FollowButton *follow = [[FollowButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 62, 34)];
UIBarButtonItem *followButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:follow];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = followButton;

BackButton *back = [[BackButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 108, 34)];
[back addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:back];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: It looks like your TitleView is too big. Just step in to the code and see how big screen is, and your question will be answered.   

[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width

Comment: That doesn't make sense though, if I leave the leftBarButtonItem a fairly small size, and make the rightBarButtonItem huge, to the point where it's filling most of the navigation bar, the titleView gets auto-resized and the text gets truncated (as expected) to fit in the tiny remaining area.

If I do the opposite, with the rightBarButtonItem small and the leftBarButtonItem huge, the leftBarButtonItem gets hidden. I would expect that the titleView would resize to fit between them.

Answer (score 1):

Make compression resistance priority higher of `BackButton`

Answer (score 0):

Can you check for the titlebar buttons width? Does it actually shrink or does the x-position just change and it gets pushed off the screen.... If the width is actually becoming "0" than you should be able to force set it back to the desired width after the loading of the other buttons is done.

Comment: I wish it was shrinking, that would be easier to fix. Nope, the size stays the same and gets hidden. The desired behaviour would be for the titleView to shrink, as it does when the left and right buttons are switched.

Comment: But can you decrease the width programmatically of the thing forcing it to disappear?